# Creating an event through the ST Developer Portal's API Console

Tags: social-tables

I'm trying to create an event using the API console and keep getting errors. Any ideas why?

I've been using different versions of the example value:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "status": "string",
  "event_id": "string",
  "start_epoch": 0,
  "end_epoch": 0,
  "industry": "string",
  "archived": true,
  "deleted": true,
  "legacy_id": 0,
  "is_public": true
}
```

I get the following back. Any thoughts?

```
{
  "code": "BadRequestError",
  "message": "[\"Has time can't be blank\",\"true is not included in the list\"]"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to fetch the user/team information first

- Once you have your oauth token from above and set to the Authorization header, make a call to https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Authentication/get_4_0_oauth_token
- This will give you the user and team object back to make subsequent calls to make events
- Once you have the team_id you can now make events
- You can POST to /4.0/events
- Swagger doc: https://developer-portal.socialtables.com/api-console#!/Events/post_4_0_events

Example POST payload:

`{
  "name": "NAME",
  "description": "DESCRIPTION",
  "status": "new",
  "start_epoch": TIME_IN_MS,
  "end_epoch": TIME_IN_MS,
  "industry": "INDUSTRY_TYPE",
  “has_time”: 1 // 0 = all day event, 1 = from/to a specific time in day
}`

- This will return the event ID under `data.event.id` in the response from the above POST
- You can then link the user to:
https://home.socialtables.com/events/EVENT_ID

Comment: So team_id is required even though the API console says it isn't? I didn't create or configure any team from the front end. Is there documentation on how to do that?